# Google play store country - what does it mean?

Tags: android

I read several Stackoverflow posts which are discussing about "Changing Play Store Country". But, till now, I could not understand what exactly it meant by "Play Store Country"

Does Google maintain different play stores based on country(Like US Play Store, India Play Store, Italy Play Store) and play store app in android phone connects to one of these stores while downloading apps?

or

Google maintains only one play store and it's responses to our android play store app changes based the location/country from where we connected to Google play store?

Please help me understand.

Comment: You can choose in which country your app will exist. So when you accsess from another, you would not be able to get app.

Comment: So play store country means.. country from which device is connecting to Google play store, right?

Comment: your app is only available in those country which is selected by you from play store developer console country list.

Comment: @pendyalasyam Yes

Comment: The country of your device won't change even if you will move to another country for a temporary time... read this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/ElWnstOsb1w